# Copy some k,v from existing JSON to constitute another JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, jmespath

I have this JSON :

```
{
    "duration": 1942,
    "frame_id": 0,
    "detect1": [
        {
            "type": {
                "s_type1": [
                    {
                        "confidence": 98.70016,
                        "klass": -1,
                        "name": "c*****"
                    },
                    {
                        "confidence": 1.042385,
                        "klass": -1,
                        "name": "c*****"
                    },
                    {
                        "confidence": 0.1587732,
                        "klass": -1,
                        "name": "s*****"
                    }
                ],
                "s_type2": [
                    {
                        "confidence": 92.82484,
                        "klass": -1,
                        "name": "b*****"
                    },
                    {
                        "confidence": 7.098834,
                        "klass": -1,
                        "name": "b*****"
                    },
                    {
                        "confidence": 0.02423214,
                        "klass": -1,
                        "name": "p*****"
                    },

                ],
                "Box": [
                    80.80994,
                    170.0965,
                    1091.778
                ]
            },
            "confidences": [
                90.08681,
                99.91595,
                90.12489

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And i would like to save some of key and values from this JSON to another JSON. The new JSON will keep :

- `duration` (k,v),
- `frame_id` (k,v),
- `detect1` :

  - `type` : `s_type1` and `s_type2` only the first dict will be keped and the `klass` (k,v) will be removed,
  - `Box` (k,v)
- `confidences` (k,v)

The final result :

```
{
    "duration": 1942,
    "frame_id": 0,
    "detect1": [
        {
            "type": {
                "s_type1": [
                    {
                        "confidence": 98.70016,
                        "name": "c*****"
                    },
                ],
                "s_type2": [
                    {
                        "confidence": 92.82484,
                        "name": "b*****"
                    }
                ],
                "Box": [
                    80.80994,
                    170.0965,
                    1091.778
                ]
            },
            "confidences": [
                90.08681,
                99.91595,
                90.12489

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was trying to do it with the JMESPath library but I can't get a good result.

Have someone any idea to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: how could define which value you should keep and which one have to move?

Comment: the initial result is an output of an ALPR process, and the final result that I will want to keep is arbitrary and depends on what I want to do with it in another python program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jmespath` to get your desired output:

```py
import jmespath
expression = """{duration: duration, 
                 frame_id: frame_id, 
                 detect1: [{type:{s_type1: [detect1[].type.s_type1[].merge({confidence: confidence, name: name})|[0]],                                                               
                                  s_type2: [detect1[].type.s_type2[].merge({confidence: confidence, name: name})|[0]],
                                  Box: detect1[].type.Box[]},
                            confidences: detect1[].confidences[]  
                           }
                           ]}
             """

expression = jmespath.compile(expression)

expression.search(json)

{'duration': 1942,
 'frame_id': 0,
 'detect1': [{'type': {'s_type1': [{'confidence': 98.70016, 'name': 'c*****'}],
    's_type2': [{'confidence': 92.82484, 'name': 'b*****'}],
    'Box': [80.80994, 170.0965, 1091.778]},
   'confidences': [90.08681, 99.91595, 90.12489]}]}
```